# VLOOKUP. I have read and followed the directions for VLOOKUP, but I cannot get it to work.

Tags: replace, match, vlookup

I have read the other questions regarding Vlookup. I have my formula, but it is not working. I have a column of Zip-Codes in column e. I want to look for a matching zip-code in column m and then replace it with the county in column n. Please can you help me? Here is the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2:E7807,M2:N962,2,false).
```

I have also tried using just 1 cell (E2) at the beginning of the formula instead of a range (E2:E7807).

Comment: Is this an Excel formula?

Answer (score 1):

Try below in the first cell.

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,$M$2:$N$962,2,false)
```

and copy and paste this cell in all required range of cells.

Comment: I am getting an error using:     =VLOOKUP(E2,$M$2:$N$962,2,FALSE)

Comment: can you please let me know, what error message that you are getting? and which cell you are pasting this formula?

Comment: Ahhh... the light dawns! The zip-codes in column E had to be convert from text to numbers. Now it is working. Thank you so much, very helpful and now I can continue my work. :)

Comment: @zephyz, if this answer provides an answer to your question, don't forget to accept it! :)